# How to deal with the mold in kitchen

Tags: kitchens, safety, mold, kitchen-sink, kitchen-counters

How do I deal with this in kitchen

Are all these just algae or something else ? Is it really harmful to health ? like we have to make sure it's 100% not there.

Here you can see light grey colour stuff on kitchen sink silicone

[image]

Here you can see black color stuff on Water purifier exit pipe

[image]

[image]

Here you can see greenish color stuff on kitchen sink filter bucket

[image]

[image]

Comment: A good cleaning with some bleach/similar mixed with soap and water should remove/kill it.  Will need testing to tell what it is exactly, but small sections usually not worth it if cleaned up.

Comment: Except the black colour stuff on water pipe, I regularly clean once in a week, but it still returns.

Comment: Have you tried bleach?

Comment: @Huesmann - I used, dishwashing liquid on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That stuff is not likely to harm you unless you decide to lick it.

That said what you show need a good cleaning.  Use a bleach based product and a scrubbing pad.  Rinse well.

To keep the areas from returning to that state, clean them regularly.

Comment: I have heard if it's mold or milddew , it can range of diseases not sure if it spreads through air .. like you said one has to lick it to enter into the body and cause some harm I guess

Comment: Air borne black mold can be dangerous if inhaled over extended periods.  Relax and clean the kitchen.